# Word2Vec with negative sampling python implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, word2vec

I'm trying to implement word2vec with negative sampling in python almost from scratch and quite new in neural networks and faced some issues. Would be very appreciate for any help.

So, I wrote simple nn with a forward pass. I didn't get which element have to have grad_fn, I'd been getting error like 'tensor have no grad_fn' until I add requires_grad_() on the returning value. Is that correct?

```py
dataset = Word2VecNegativeSampling(data, num_negative_samples, 30000)
dataset.generate_dataset()
wordvec_dim = 10


class Word2VecNegativeSamples(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_tokens):
        super(Word2VecNegativeSamples, self).__init__()
        self.input = nn.Linear(num_tokens, 10, bias=False)
        self.output = nn.Linear(10, num_tokens, bias=False)
        self.num_tokens = num_tokens

    def forward(self, input_index_batch, output_indices_batch):
        '''
        Implements forward pass with negative sampling
    
        Arguments:
        input_index_batch - Tensor of ints, shape: (batch_size, ), indices of input words in the batch
        output_indices_batch - Tensor if ints, shape: (batch_size, num_negative_samples+1),
                                indices of the target words for every sample
    
        Returns:
        predictions - Tensor of floats, shape: (batch_size, num_negative_samples+1)
        '''
        results = []
        batch_size = len(input_index_batch)
    
        for i in range(batch_size):
            input_one_hot = torch.zeros(self.num_tokens)
            input_one_hot[input_index_batch[i]] = 1
    
            forward_result = self.output(self.input(input_one_hot))
            results.append(torch.tensor([forward_result[out_index] for out_index in output_indices_batch[i]]))
        return torch.stack(results).requires_grad_()


nn_model = Word2VecNegativeSamples(data.num_tokens())
nn_model.type(torch.FloatTensor)
```

After all i'm trying to train the model, but neither loss nor accuracy changing. Is the code for model prediction correct as well?

Here is training code:

```
def train_neg_sample(model, dataset, train_loader, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs):    
    loss = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss().type(torch.FloatTensor)
    loss_history = []
    train_history = []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        model.train() # Enter train mode
    
    dataset.generate_dataset()        
    loss_accum = 0
    correct_samples = 0
    total_samples = 0
    for i_step, (inp, out, lab) in enumerate(train_loader):
        prediction = model(inp, out) 
        loss_value = loss(prediction, lab)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_value.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        _, indices = torch.max(prediction, 1)
        correct_samples += torch.sum(indices == 0)
        
        total_samples += lab.shape[0]
        
        loss_accum += loss_value
    
    scheduler.step()
    ave_loss = loss_accum / i_step
    train_accuracy = float(correct_samples) / total_samples
    
    loss_history.append(float(ave_loss))
    train_history.append(train_accuracy)
    
    print("Epoch#: %i, Average loss: %f, Train accuracy: %f" % (epoch, ave_loss, train_accuracy))
    
return loss_history, train_history
```

Answer (score 0):

If your loss function is not changing, it's highly probable that you register the wrong set of parameters to the optimizer. Can you post the code snippet where you initialize your model and optimizer? It is supposed to look like this:

```
nn_model = Word2VecNegativeSamples(data.num_tokens())
optimizer = optim.SGD(nn_model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```